# PHP/CURL Ответ приходит символами

Tags: php, curl, qiwi

Подскажите как декодировать ответ, делаю запрос по API QIWI но в ответ приходят символы

```
$headers = array(
"Accept: application/json",
"Authorization: Bearer {МОЙ КЛЮЧ}",
"Content-Type: application/pdf",);



$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "{МОЙ_ЮРЛ}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$out = curl_exec($curl);
$binary = json_encode($out);

curl_close($curl);
print_r($out);
```

Вот скрин того что приходит в ответ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы запрашиваете PDF, Вам и приходит PDF. А декодировать его как json вряд ли получится. Смотрите в документацию, что именно должно приходить и реагируйте соответствующе.

Comment: ммм, просили pdf - получили pdf. В чём проблема?

Comment: @KoVadim в документации написано, что ответ приходил в application/pdf, как конвертировать это в читабельный pdf ?

Comment: просто сохраните это в файл и должен быть нормальный читаемый файл. Или просто печатайте только содержимое через print. А если печатать и заголовки, то будет конечно странно выглядеть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас `CURLOPT_HEADER` выводит заголовки в ответ, уберите эту опцию.
можете также отправить `header('Content-type: application/pdf')` и выводите свой пдф через `echo/print`

Comment: Сделал как Вы написали, все равно выводятся символы, без заголовков но символы

Comment: @VladRublenko ну так если ты добавляешь на вывод еще что-то другое, то и выводит конкатекацию.